# How to prevent currency rounding errors with decimal variable type?

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding-error

I am working on a payment plan calculator. I switched from 'double' to 'decimal' variable types to prevent rounding errors but I am still getting one somewhere. I came up with this data-set to use to test my code because there is a clear remainder:

Balance: $1,575.75
Down Payment: $500.00
Remaining Balance: $1,075.75
Number of Payments after the Down Payment: 9
Installment Amount: $119.53 (x8)
Remainder: $119.51

I switched my datatypes from double to decimal (obviously)
I tried re-writing the code multiple times calculating the same things in different ways (which is why some of the math at this point is less than 'minimalist')
I tried making my code more modular to find the rounding error

```
// Method within my WinForms project
public void CalculateInstallmentPayments()
{
    decimal currentBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBalanceInput.Text); // Current Balance
    decimal downPayment = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDownPayment.Text); // Down Payment
    decimal installmentCount = sliderRemainingPmtCount.Value; // Installment Count
    decimal balanceAfterDP = currentBalance - downPayment; // Balance After Down Payment
    decimal installmentAmount = (balanceAfterDP / installmentCount); // Installment Amount
    decimal remainderPayment = (balanceAfterDP - (installmentAmount * (installmentCount - 1))); // Final Payment (Remainder)

    // Using Rich Text box as a 'Console' for debugging
    rtxtNotate.Text = ($"Current Balance: {currentBalance.ToString()}\nDown Payment: {downPayment.ToString("C")}\n" +
        $"Installment Count: {installmentCount.ToString()}\nInstallment Amount: {installmentAmount.ToString("C")}\n" +
        $"Remainder: {remainderPayment.ToString("C")}\n");
}
```

This is currently the output:

Current Balance: 1575.75
Down Payment: $500.00
Installment Count: 9
Installment Amount: $119.53
Remainder: $119.53 -- This is the rounding error. It should read $119.51

I've been refactoring this code for hours and I feel like I'm missing something incredibly simple.

Comment: It is one of the few good reasons to use Math.Round(), you need to calculate the installment payment to an amount that can actually be paid.  Accurate to a penny, no more.

Answer (score 1):

You're not rounding off the down payment amount before you apply it. So you're getting the correct result with no (or very very small) rounding errors... for someone making payments of about $119.52777777777

If you round the installment amount before you store it in the installmentAmount variable you might get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I caught that above and it was the correct answer but to format it the way you did is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `decimal` data type is not a fixed point type with two decimals, it is a base ten flloating point.

You can use it to prevent only some specific forms of rounding errors that occur when converting a `number` that has an exact representation in base ten, to base two, such as 0.1

But `1075.75 / 9 = 119.5277777`...

This is not a `number` that can be represented exactly in base 10 or in base 2, so you will get some (incredibly small) rounding error even with `decimal`.

But that is not actually your problem. You manually round the numbers with `toString("c")`. You round to 2 digits there in the output, but the calculations still use a lot more digits in the background.

So the remainder as well as the installment is `119.52777777777` and it all add up. When you round it to two digits afterwards, it looks like you are missing cents. If you want to calculate the remainder using the rounded installment, you have to round it yourself, using `Math.Round()`

Answer (score 0):

Update the installmentAmount calculation as below

```
decimal installmentAmount = Math.Round((balanceAfterDP / installmentCount),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
decimal currentBalance = 1575.75M; // Current Balance
        decimal downPayment = 500.00M; // Down Payment
        decimal installmentCount = 9; // Installment Count
        decimal balanceAfterDP = currentBalance - downPayment; // Balance After Down Payment
        decimal installmentAmount = Math.Round((balanceAfterDP / installmentCount),2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Installment Amount
        decimal remainderPayment = (balanceAfterDP - (installmentAmount * (installmentCount - 1))); // Final Payment (Remainder)
```

and you will get the right value : 119.51